# How to start a GUI program in a VM with PHP

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, virtual-machine, php, remote-desktop

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 VM running on my online server where there is no display attached.

I want to start `Teamviewer` there on that VM to get graphical access to that server.

I guess I have to give the PHP user www-data somehow sudo access to start the Teamviewer GUI in a virtual X-Session via `gksu`.

How would I have to configure sudo to achieve this?

And how could I call that from within a PHP-script on an Apache, that is running on that server?

(I could install another desktop environment if that would be more performant)

Comment: Is there some particular reason why you can't just log in to the server and start it there? Why mix in PHP at all? And why is it a consideration that the machine is virtualized (as opposed to simply headless)?

Comment: I normally use vncserver for graphical access. after you login run vncserver and  then use vncviewer to connect to your vncserver session.

Comment: I am selling a complete installation of a pre configured Ubuntu in a vm with a php application running on it. So I would like to be able to login into firefox on that machine through Teamviewer

Comment: Since the VM is not important in my case, I started a new question without the mentioning of VM:

[How to start a GUI program with PHP from website](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78281/how-to-start-a-gui-program-with-php-from-website)